# Parser dex file for bytecode retrive

Tags: java, android, parsing, bytecode, dex

I'm trying to parse a file dex, I have written the Java code to get information about:

- List item
- header
- string_ids
- type_ids
- proto_ids
- field_ids
- method_ids
- class_defs

simply with the byte shift based on the size of the individual fields.

Now I want to get the bytecode then the source code, the dex file in question.
Maybe this information can be found in the structure "code_item"?
If so, at what point do I block of memory to be able to read it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The DEX file format is described in detail here: http://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html .  The dexdump tool includes a disassembler; looking through the sources for that may be enlightening: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/dexdump/DexDump.cpp .

Answer (score 5):

You might take a look at the [dexlib2 library](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/tree/master/dexlib2/src/main/java/org/jf/dexlib2) that's part of the [smali/baksmali](http://smali.org) project. It provides an easy-to-use api for accessing the information in a dex file.

Example code:

```
DexFile dexFile = DexFileFactory.loadDexFile("blah.dex", 15);

for (ClassDef classDef: dexFile.getClasses()) {
  for (Method method: classDef.getMethods()) {
    MethodImplementation impl = method.getImplementation();
    if (impl != null) {
      for (Instruction instruction: impl.getInstructions()) {
        // process instruction as needed...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is a good solution thanks. Thank you for the tools :)
However, I am trying to get information at lower level.
I would understand, how to get to print the bytecode file, and then know the location and length of the data elements contained in the file structure.

Comment: As fadden mentioned, the dex-format.html document is the way to go. It has all the information you need to parse it.